# Commands not running with no error message

Tags: discord.js, quick.db

im trying to run multiple commands for my discord bot, bot for some reason one singular command is not running. This is the code in my main.js file:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'petfeed') {
        client.commands.get('petfeed').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }else if(command === 'petwater') {
        client.commands.get('petwater').execute(message, args, Discord); 
        //this is one of the commands that runs perfectly fine. The command has virtually identical code to the petfeed command in its file but with a few small changes
});
```

Here is the command that i am trying to run:

```
const db = require('quick.db')

module.exports = {
    name: 'petfeed',
    description: 'feeds your pet',
    execute: async (message, args, Discord) => {
        let user = message.author
        let fullness = await db.fetch(`fullness_${user.id}`)
        let food = await db.fetch(`food_${user.id}`)

        if(fullness === null) fullness = 0;
        if(food === null) food = 0;
        
        if(fullness < 3 && food >= 1) {
            db.add(`fullness_${user.id}`, 1)
            db.subtract(`food_${user.id}`, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

I have other very similar commands that run perfectly fine, but this command does nothing when i try to run it, and it doesn't give back any errors.

Comment: Can you add a console.log() to the command file so you can see if it runs at all.

Comment: @mmoomocow i put one as the first line after the execute and still nothing

Comment: Did you save the file and restart the bot? because console.log() should have worked if the module have been loaded.

Comment: @Radnerus yes i did, twice just to make sure

Comment: can you show an example of how you would run another command

Comment: i edited the original message to show another command that does run in the main.js file, the code that runs when its called is almost identical to the petfeed code but with a few small changes.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow changing the name to petfood in both the main.js file and the command file fixed the issue. If i change it back to petfeed it stops working again.